# Unable to get UDP response

Tags: c#, asp.net, udp

I was creating a website in asp.net for my company to monitor different servers, but now I am stuck.

In one function, I want the UDP response time of one of the servers, as I am able to send the UDP packet but unable to get the response from the server. The request is received by server correctly.  How can I do this?

Here is the code:

```
    byte[] byteData;  
    IPEndPoint ipeSender;
    EndPoint epSender;
    Socket serverSocket;
    IPEndPoint ipe;
    EndPoint eps;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byteData = new byte[1024];
        ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.4.25"), 2015);
        epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        serverSocket.Bind(epSender);
        byte[] byteData1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("3^12062012152936041^OARAREGIONXWEB^SDHS^1^0^40^3^0^8^Register^");


        serverSocket.SendTo(byteData1, eps);

        ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("70.88.142.138"), 2015);
        eps = (EndPoint)ipe;
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnNetworkBytesReceived), epSender);

    }


    private void OnNetworkBytesReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
            if (serverSocket == null)
                return;
            //if(epSender.ToString()!= dw[1, RowIndex].Value.ToString())
            //  return; // serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnNetworkBytesReceived), epSender);

            int DataLength = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epSender);

            byte[] TempBytes = new byte[DataLength];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, 0, TempBytes, 0, DataLength);

            serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnNetworkBytesReceived), epSender);

        }
        catch (SocketException socexp)
        {

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException objexp)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're sure your code looks OK, the next thing to check for firewalls (including Windows firewall, and any A/V firewalls).

Comment: i have checked them also, the are ok.

Comment: Have you tried doing a synchronous recieve using `ReceiveFrom`? I would expect that the ASP.NET request to complete and terminate the async receive before you get a reply.

Comment: yes, but it is also not working.

Comment: Please guys, help...!!!